# How can I build a popup in drupal?

Tags: 7

I am working with Drupal 7, and I have a block generated by the Views module with titles of many articles. When the user chooses a title, I want a popup with title, body, and image to appear.

Is it possible with any module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [lightbox2](http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2) module.

And [here](http://drupal.org/node/252260) is the description that how will you use it.

Comment: This option is a good option.  However, for drupal 7, there is a mistake, I have applied a patch and the module with views doesn't work correctly...

Comment: hmmm, but I did not check it with views. You can check this link. http://drupal.org/node/252260. Check the sections of links created with views.

Comment: I don't know if I trying correctly this option.  Do you have any example about how apply the code is shown in "the sections of links created with views"?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  In views filter I added the field "Title".  I put the option "rewrite the output" and I put this code:  <a href="/project/node/[nid]/lightbox2" rel="lightframe[group|width:400px;][caption]">[title]</a>  Then in the section header I have added a field Global Text Area and I put the code appears in "The sections of links created with views" in full html. and nothing, what is my error?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using lightbox2 for poupup node and content type ,etc (every thing except iamges) is not standard method work but not adequate way.
If you have drupal developing knowledge i suggest you use ctools modal
[ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools)
[automodal module](http://drupal.org/project/ctools_automodald)
[modal-forms](http://drupal.org/project/modal_forms)
[useful example](http://www.angrydonuts.com/ctools-presentation-slides-and-example-code)